# DataPager, change count items

Tags: asp.net, datapager

I'm using a DataPager control, I want to change count items on each page.

For example : 
the First page 6 rows, the second page 311, the third page 12, etc.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my advice is to do it manually, make your own sql query and customize the page size as you want

here are some tips that can help

- to get range of rows that are needed for pagination user the row number

[MS-sql row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

- use the TOP to get the upper set of rows

  select TOP 5 * from ....
- for sure you'll need to get specific row numbers that will be displayed in the current page

  select (--get row number--) from tbl_smth where row_num>5 and row_num<10

were as i guess that you have the page sizes in an array so you have to count them to determine the two numbers {5,10}

hope this will help